# Functions in dictionaries in python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, syntax

I can store functions in dictionaries by saying

```
MyDict = {}

def func():
    print("Hello, world!")

MyDict["func"] = func
```

I was wondering if there was a cleaner/neater way to write this - something along the lines of

```
MyDict = {}

def MyDict["func"]():
    print("Hello, world!")
```

However this code throws a syntax error

Comment: Have you considered using a class?

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't really what you want to do overall. Are you defining functions so distinct that there cannot be a common base?

Comment: Never used a class, can someone give an example of how to use it for this case.

Comment: You could use `lambda` functions. But the cleanest way would be to use the full function definition. Or use a class.

Comment: The "cleanest" way of writing this is how your first code block is written, to be honest. However, this screams a design issue to me overall.

Comment: @the_constant For production-level code, this would definitely be a design issue, but to me the question does not look like that. Also answering questions like "how can I make this work?" with something like "believe me, you don't want to know the answer" is not very helpful, I think OP will get to that point by himself after learning more about Python. :)

Comment: @NiklasMertsch completely agree. That was all my intention by stating the first block was the cleanest code too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can (ab)use a decorator.

```
MyDict = {}

def store(d, name):
    def _(f):
        d[name] = f
        return f
    return _

@store(MyDict, "func")
def func():
    print("Hello, world!")

@store(MyDict, "foo")
def some_other_func():
    print("Goodbye")
```

You can simplify this if you just want to use the defined name as the key and hard-code the dictionary to update:

```
def store(f):
    MyDict[f.__name__] = f
    return f

@store
def func():
    print("Hello, world!")
```

Answer (score 2):

For your example you can do this:

```
d = {}
d['func'] = lambda: print('Hello, world!')
d['func']()
>>> 'Hello, world!'
```

If you want to use a class:

```
class MyClass:
    def func(self):
        print('Hello, world!')

c = MyClass()
c.func()
>>> 'Hello, world!'
```

Comment: Is there a solution for multiline functions?

Comment: For multiline functions, you definitely want to use a class

Comment: ... or just use a full function definition.

Comment: If OP has "never used a class", I'm inclined to believe classes are better suited to his purpose than a dict of functions.

Comment: I'm inclined to not use classes where there is no shared state between the methods.

Comment: Not to mention the ability to iterate over the `dict` and calling every function instead of having to inspect what is actually a method of an object, should that need exist

Comment: Sure those are fair use cases for a dict of functions. Given the context though, I doubt that is the best solution. Feel free to add your own answer if you disagree with my interpretation of the question.

Comment: The OP is clearly re-inventing classes in the initial request, and has never used them. I think much of the nuance in the last few comments is well beyond the OPs current understanding.

Comment: @MatthewStory I'm failing to interpret "clearly" when there's no mention of state whatsoever, or even a suggestion of needing access control / modification of any kind.

Comment: @bphi i don't want to create a new answer, as yours is fine, but what about putting the functions in a separate module?

Comment: @joelb that's definitely correct in some cases, but without additional feedback from OP I'm not sure we can determine the "right way" in this instance.

Comment: As `func(self)` is not making use of the inner state of an instance (`self`), wouldn't it be better to use declare `func()` as a `@staticmethod`? This would additionally have the benefit of not needing initialization (`c = MyClass()`). Imo it is misleading to initialize an instance of a class without ever treating it as an instance. Just use a static method by calling `MyClass.func()`.

Comment: Classes are suitable for what I'm trying to accomplish, thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
def MyDict["func"]():
    print("Hello, world!")
```

because after `def` you need to use some word that contains only [allowed characters](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier). That's why you got Syntax error.

What you can use is:

1) [Lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) functions (as suggested by @bphi)

```
MyDict = {}
MyDict['func'] = lambda: print("123")
MyDict['func']()
```

2) Python [class](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html) to dynamically create methods (inside the class) which are stored in `MyDict`, using [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) built-in function:

```
def func1():
    print(1)


def func2():
    print(2)


MyDict = {}
MyDict['func1'] = func1
MyDict['func2'] = func2

class MyClass3:
    def __init__(self):
        for name, obj in MyDict.items():
            setattr(self, name, obj)

obj = MyClass3()
obj.func1()
obj.func2()
```

or via lambda:

```
MyDict = {}
MyDict['func1'] = lambda : print(1)
MyDict['func2'] = lambda : print(2)

class MyClass3:
    def __init__(self):
        for name, obj in MyDict.items():
            setattr(self, name, obj)

obj = MyClass3()
obj.func1()
obj.func2()
```

or

```
class MyClass3:
    MyDict = {}
    MyDict['func1'] = lambda: print(1)
    MyDict['func2'] = lambda: print(2)

    def __init__(self):
        for name, obj in self.MyDict.items():
            setattr(self, name, obj)

obj = MyClass3()
obj.func1()
obj.func2()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can express all your functions as one-liners, use `lambda`s as suggested in  [@bphi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51051934/9568847).

If you don't want to be rescricted by using the lambda calculus, another way is to use a class and its static methods. Static methods are methods of a class, not an instance of a class, so they don't have access to the inner state of an object and can be called on the class, not an instance.

However, by reading through this answer you might see why this is not a very elegant (or recommended) approach, even though the result is exactly what you asked for.

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod # this decorator is optional here, but suggested for code clarity
    def func():
        print("Hello, world!")

    def func2():
        print("Hey there, I am another function.")

MyClass.func()
>>> 'Hello, world!'
MyClass.func()
>>> 'Hey there, I am another function.'
```

If you want to use the syntax of dictionaries as proposed in your question, you can use `__dict__` on the class:

```
MyDict = dict(MyClass.__dict__)

MyDict["func"]()
>>> 'Hello, world!'
MyDict["func2"]()
>>> 'Hey there, I am another function.'
```

And you can also add other functions to that dictionary:

```
MyDict["func3"] = lambda: print("Hi, I am yet another function.")

def func4:
    print("And I am the last function for today.")

MyDict["func4"] = func4

MyDict["func"]()
>>> 'Hi, I am yet another function.'
MyDict["func2"]()
>>> 'And I am the last function for today.'
```

But as this dictionary is just a representation of the class `MyClass`, it also contains some items related to that class, like `__weakref__`. But you can extract your own functions:

```
MyCleanDict = {}
for key, value in MyDict:
    if not key.startswith("_"):
        MyCleanDict[key] = value
```

The result is exactly what you asked for, but I doubt the complexity of the approach is worth the result. I recommend a) using `lambda`-functions, b) staying at your first approach (define the functions first and then put them in a `dict`) or c) rethink your actual problem as you may find another solution besides storing functions in a dictionary.